# Как лучше хранить config переменные в Python проекте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу писать тг-бота, но текст и путь к изображениям хочу хранить в отдельных переменных, чтобы код был примерно такой

`bot.send_message(..., MESSAGE_1)`

вместо такого

`bot.send_message(..., "Сообщение 1")`

Как лучше всего это сделать?
Работать с файлами config, хранить все переменные в отдельном py файле а потом импортировать?
Что порекомендуете?

Comment: Например, можно использовать модуль [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/), он умеет брать настройки из переменных окружения, файлов `.env` или `settings.ini`